# How to retrieve image using jsp in chrome?

Tags: eclipse, image, jsp, google-chrome

I have been using eclipse for j2ee and main code is written in jsp
I was successful in displaying image in eclipse,mozilla and edge but my jsp does not retrieve image in chrome
my tag goes this way

Also i got the same problem when using my jsp as a value for background-image attribute 
which is

```
<div style="background-image=url(retrieve.jsp?id=2)">
```

Comment: my tags are 
<img src="retrieve.jsp?id=2" width=130 height=130>
<div style="background-image=url(retrieve.jsp?id=2)">

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow, suggest you review :https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  - you should include some code, so we can see what you are trying

Comment: I tried but it did not show so i pasted it in comment